# phantom has no method 'create'

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

i'm trying to use phamtom into node express app.

For testing purpose i write this test

```js
'use strict' ;

var buster = require("buster"),
  phantom = require('phantom'),
  server="http://localhost:3000";
buster.spec.expose();
describe("get index page", function () {
it("is accessable", function(phantom) {
  phantom.create(function (error,ph) {
    ph.createPage(function (page) {
      ... ...
            ph.exit();
          }
        });
    });
  });
console.log('phatom.create.done') ;
});
});
```

but when test it with

```
node test/node-test-index.js
```

object phantom have no method create

```
TypeError: Object function (fn) {
              if (typeof fn !== "function") { return resolve("resolve"); }
              return function () {
                  try {
                      var retVal = fn.apply(this, arguments);
                      resolve("resolve");
                      return retVal;
                  } catch (up) {
                      resolve("reject", up);
                  }
              };
          } has no method 'create'
      at Object.<anonymous>     (/home/hebus/Documents/git/system/nodejs/searchEs/test/node-test-index.js:25:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the variable reference in the local scope if the `it` callback. Don't reuse variable names!

```
it("is accessable", function(done) {
```

The other thing that is wrong with your code is the error argument for the `phantom.create()` callback.

If you really are using the `phantom` module, then you need to change

```
phantom.create(function (error,ph) {
```

to

```
phantom.create(function (ph) {
```

If not, then you should use

```
var phantom = require('node-phantom');
```

This is a very similar bridge between node.js and PhantomJS.